# Powrshell Template to expedite script creation

Tags: powershell, templates

Been writing more and more scripts, specifically to make API calls, get information, and alert of certain conditions are met. The alerts are sent to microsoft teams channel. These scripts are run untended as scheduled tasks. I only use powershell v5+

I've attempted to make a simple template to start from, with what I've found online and made some modifications. I need error checking and reporting, which I feel can be done through Try/Catch/Finally. I also want some basic logging output to go in and check for errors.

Will the logging in the final block be sufficient to know the date and time the script completed? Will using the $error.Does the exception catch the error message? I seem to have luck using it and some times I don't. What am I leaving out that is critical in ensuring a script runs unattended and that errors get reported when there's a problem. I will also be including a block of code in the Catch section to send the error to the MS teams channel.

```
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    <Overview of script>

.SYNTAX
    <Cmdlet-Name> -Parameter <value>

.DESCRIPTION
    <Brief description of script>

.PARAMETER <Parameter_Name>
    <Brief description of parameter input required. Repeat this attribute if required>

.INPUTS
    <Inputs if any, otherwise state None>

.OUTPUTS
    <Outputs if any, otherwise state None - example: Log file stored in C:\Windows\Temp\<name>.log>

.EXAMPLE
    <Example goes here. Repeat this attribute for more than one example>

.REMARKS
    Version:        1.0
    Author:         <Name>
    Creation Date:  <Date>
#>

#---------------------------------------------------------[Variables]------------------------------------------------------------

$var1 = <stuff>
$var2 = <stuff>

#---------------------------------------------------------[Import Modules]--------------------------------------------------------

Import-Module <name>

#-----------------------------------------------------------[Functions]------------------------------------------------------------

Function <FunctionName> {
    [CmdletBindinging()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$MyOptionalParameter,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [int]$MyMandatoryParameter
    )

    Try{
        <code goes here>
    }

    Catch {
        Write-Host $Error.Exception
        Out-File $Error.Exception
        Break
    }

    Finally {
        $time = Get-Date
        "Script completed at $time" | Out-File $env:TEMP\MyScriptName.log
    }
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------[Execution]------------------------------------------------------------

<FunctionName>
```

Comment: in the catch block, you want to use `$_.Exception.Messge` if you are only interested in the error.. otherwise you can do `$_.Exception` as well to get the details. Logging in Finally block will always execute regardless of what happens in try/catch and log the **time of exit only**. You might need to add more logging as to when your call starts. Not quite clear what else you are looking for

Comment: Not looking for much else. Just want a simple shell that all my scripts can start from. I need to log that it started and finished, any errors if the script fails, and alert on script execution failure.